# Bootstrap CSS design in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have this design in MVC...

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 remove-padd-right">
                    <div class="side-A">
                        <div class="product-thumb">
                            <div class="image">
                                <a><img src="~/img/hotels/@item.Images.FirstOrDefault().Image" style="height:281px;" class="img-responsive" alt="Avatar"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="side-B">
                        <div class="product-desc-side">
                            <h3><a>@item.Name</a></h3>
                            <p>
                                <span class="fa fa-address-book-o"></span> @item.Address<br />
                                <span class="fa fa-react"></span> @item.Reviews.Count Reviews    <br />
                                @item.Ratings.Count Ratings
                            </p>

                            <div class="links"><a href="@Href("~/Hotels/Details/"+item.Id)">View details</a></div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>

            }
```

I need to make the design just like in simple HTML like this...

```
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 remove-padd-right">
                                <div class="side-A">
                                    <div class="product-thumb">
                                        <div class="image">
                                            <a><img src="images/category1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="image"></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="side-B">
                                    <div class="product-desc-side">
                                        <h3><a>luxury spa</a></h3>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec adipiscing elit. Nunc lorem nulla, ornare eu felis luctus non maximus vitae, portt neque. ipsum dolor sit amet, consec adipiscing elit.</p>
                                        <div class="links"><a href="single-blog.html">Read more</a></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 remove-padd-left">
                                <div class="side-A">
                                    <div class="product-thumb">
                                        <div class="image">
                                            <a><img alt="image" class="img-responsive" src="images/category2.png"></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="side-B">
                                    <div class="product-desc-side">
                                        <h3><a>Beatusish ingl</a></h3>
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec adipiscing elit. Nunc lorem nulla, ornare eu felis luctus non maximus vitae, portt neque. ipsum dolor sit amet, consec adipiscing elit.</p>
                                        <div class="links"><a href="single-blog.html">Read more</a></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 remove-padd-right">
                            <div class="side-A">
                                <div class="product-desc-side">
                                    <h3><a>luxury room</a></h3>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec adipiscing elit. Nunc lorem nulla, ornare eu felis luctus non maximus vitae, portt neque. ipsum dolor sit amet, consec adipiscing elit.</p>
                                    <div class="links"><a href="single-blog.html">Read more</a></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="side-B">
                                <div class="product-thumb">
                                    <div class="image txt-rgt">
                                        <a class="arrow-left"><img src="images/category3.png" class="img-responsive" alt="imaga"></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

How to achieve this design in MVC. I'm confused. Please help. Refer the screenshot of both codes, I'm fetching the details from the database in MVC. 
MVC Screenshot -
[Implemented in MVC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1QCO.png) 
HTML screenshot -
[In simple HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jo15.png)

Comment: What's the problem? It's look perfect, with only one difference between the simple HTML and the HTML of the MVC: the `<p>` tag inside `.side-B`.

Comment: The layout is controlled (at least in part) by CSS, so you'd also need to check how different CSS has been applied to the pages shown in the screenshots.

Comment: Actually I want same design as of HTML, while loading the third item, image should be in the right side, check the css of simple html of the third item. Refer to the images.

Comment: How would I check the CSS of a screenshot?

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 4? The markup appears to be for Bootstrap 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't toggle between the classes `remove-padd-right` and `remove-padd-left` after the `<div class="clear"></div>`.

**EDIT**

added code example

```
>> somewhere at the top of your view, you have something like this
@{
   Layout = "~/Views/_LayoutRoot.cshtml";

   >> add variable for toggeling classname; init with second value
   var removePaddClass = "remove-padd-left";
}

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   // swap classes for each item
   removePaddClass
      = removePaddClass == "remove-padd-right"
         ? "remove-padd-left"
         : "remove-padd-right";

   <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 @removePaddClass">
      >> ... your html
      <div class="clear"></div>
   </div>
}
```

Comment: Can you help me with the code, please! I'm a beginner in MVC. :|

Comment: Thank you @Jurgen_Rohr, now I got the idea for the implementation.